# Orthography: stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, questions

How do you spell the name of this platform correctly?

Google offers different possibilities:

1. **StackOverflow?**
2. **Stack Overflow?**
3. **Stackoverflow?**

Comment: For me all first page Google search results are only Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (Section "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name" in particular)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have this covered in the "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name" section of the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

Comment: Sniped you by 41 seconds, Hah!

Comment: @FEichinger yeah, well, I'm getting rep for this, so... ;)

Comment: Who cares about rep! :P

Comment: As soon as I gathered one hundred... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the links at the bottom of the page...

Stack Overflow

Based on the `<title>` at http://stackoverflow.com...

Stack Overflow

Based on the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page...

Stack Overflow

Shall I go on?

Comment: See also the Trademark Guidance: http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance *"Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters)."*

Answer (score 1):

In the logo it is

```
stackoverflow
```

But everywhere else it is

```
Stack Overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct name is `Stack Overflow`. It's named this in the SE site footer, as well as in documents, such as the help center and about pages.

However, in the logo at the top of the page, it reads `stackoverflow`. All lowercase, all one word.